# DAX to perform count after grouping rows

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database, dax

I have a single table in the Azure SQL database. I want to connect it to Power BI using DirectQuery and perform a calculation - count the number of jobs that failed and that are successful.

[SQL  Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wctM3.png)

There is a parent job and a child job. If the status of all child jobs is "finished", parent job is successful else, parent job failed.

In the screenshot above, job1 and job4 are successful since both of their child jobs finished but job2 and job3 failed. So, I want to create a card showing 2 jobs failed and 2 jobs successful.

I know how to do this calculation in SQL using window functions but I am struggling in DAX. I don't want to create a view in SQL and then connect to PowerBI. I want to do this with the help of DAX. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

create a table/matrix with parent_jobName on the row, and add a measure like:

```
status_parent = if( contains( [SQL Table Name], [status], "Error")
     ,"Failed"
     ,"Successful"),
```

Answer (score 0):

sample data I am using:

[image]

Add a new column with if condition like:

```
value = if ( 'datadax (2)'[Status] = "finished", 1, 0)
```

It will create a value column where it will insert 1 when status is "finished" and 0 if other than finished.

[image]

from visualization select card >> select column which you want to show on card >> select Count (Distinct)
[image]

In filters (**For Failed jobs**):

- add your newly created column
- set filter type >> Advance filtering
- Show items when the value >> is >> 0 (**For Failed jobs**)
- Show items when the value >> is greater than >> 0 (**For successed jobs**)

[image]

***OUTPUT***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It seemed to work but when I went to the next requirement, this failed.

Comment: Jobs run daily, so the next day same job name will appear in the database with a different start time. Let's say job1 was successful and job2, job3 failed on the first day and the same pattern repeated on the second day. Distinct count will return the same number which is incorrect.

Comment: I was able to solve for this based on date column. Thanks for helping :)